# sqlachemy explanation of schema generation

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy to create a schema in postgres. I cannot find a working example of the method of creating the schema via the MetaData and reflect function where one declares the name of the schema.

```
conn = db.postgres_db(host, port, database, pass, user)
postg_meta = sql.MetaData(bind=conn.engine)
postg_meta.reflect(schema='transactions')
stat_query = sql.select([sql.distinct(acocunts.c.user_id)]
```

This is a snippet of the code given to me and I am attempting to clarify where and how the schema ('transactions') is defined. I am new to sqlalchemy and the rational of some of its working pieces so I would appreciate some assistance.

Could this refer to a file with an external class where the schema is defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has the concept of a [schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) which is hierarchically ordered between the database and table like `database.schema.table`.

SQLAlchemy supports this concept of [schemas](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name) for Postgres and other databases.

Since you performing a [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects), it is implicit that this schema *already* exists in your database. This is what the `schema` keyword is referring to.

You can [confirm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40051/50880) that this is the case by listing all the schemas in your database:

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata
```